# Can I make pulsing light using AC as source, a diode and a LED?

Tags: led, ac, diodes, graph

I'm new to this branch of physics hence my stupid question.

I know that diodes are used to make current flow in only one way. If I connected an AC source to a diode and the diode to a small light bulb or led, would I get pulsing light? In theory, according to the graph of the current that the diode passes, the light should be pulsing on and off, shouldn't it?

I didn't try this yet because I don't have a transformer and I don't want to kill myself.

Comment: what is the frequency of your AC source? Apart from making the circuit work, chances are that if it is too high you won't see your led pulsing.

Comment: I think it's 60Hz. I know that's too much for human eyes to detect.

Comment: Then you have answered your own question - at least for the specified frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diode in series with an AC source over to a load will indeed pulse the current through the load. It may very well be hard for you to see it pulsing however.

For a light bulb load with a heated filament the heating time constant will tend to integrate the current pulses into an average temperature that will appear to be a fairly constant brightness to the human eye.

The light from an LED load will pulse with the applied current pulses. However at the 50 or 60 Hz of the normal AC line frequency you will be unlikely to see the flashing with your eye. The threshold for most human eyes to be able to detect a flashing light is around 22 to 25 Hz. The eye and brain perform an averaging function whose time constant is a low pass filter to 50 or 60Hz signalling.

Comment: So that means my way of reasoning holds. Is there a way to reduce the frequency?

Comment: Also, if you're ever considering putting and LED across an AC source (as you seem to be implying you might do at some point), you'll probably blow the LED very quickly. A proper current-limiting circuit would be necessary to bring the average current through the LED within its working range.

Comment: @Tamás - Reducing the frequency out of your transformer would require some additional switching circuitry to block some of the current pulses from the diode.

Comment: @Dan Laks - I see. The LED was just an ordinary example for a current consuming thing so that I can see the desired effect, but thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Tamás: AC across an incandescent lamp heats the filament on both the positive **and** negative half-cycles, the result being that the frequency of the optical ripple is twice the mains frequency as well as having a smaller dynamic range since the filament has less time to cool between half-cycles. On the other hand, an LED used as a half-wave rectifier goes totally blank for half of each cycle and the ripple is generally detectable, if not seen outright.

Comment: You may be able to visualize the pulses by waving the LED around quickly (but carefully) -- the "integration" performed by your eye will make the pulses appear as a dotted line of lights.

Comment: From personal experience, if you run an LED from a half-wave rectified 50Hz AC source, then the flickering is quite visible.  When used as a "power on" indicator, the flicker gets quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes - but.

First, in addition to the parts you listed, you would also need a current-limiting resistor. If your voltage out of the transformer is N volts, and your LED has a forward voltage Vf, and a maximum current P (in milliamps) then you can calculate the value of your resistor R (in kohms) as

R = ((N x 1.414) - .7 - Vf) / P

Actually, you would want to increase R by 20 to 50%, just to keep from hitting the LED with maximum current.

Now, here's the but. The LED will, flash, but it will flash at the frequency of the signal coming out of transformer. Since I expect you're thinking of plugging this into the wall, the LED will be flashing at 60 Hz, or 60 times per second. If you are careful, and connect your LED to the transformer with 3 or 4 feet of wire, and insulate everything with electrical tape, you can actually see this if you wave it around in a dark room. If it's stationary, you'll be out of luck.

Also, if you use a light bulb rather than an LED, you'll also be out of luck. Light bulbs don't respond fast enough.

Comment: Since the LED's Vf is rated in DC volts, it's OK to use the transformer's RMS rating to figure out the ballast resistor. Also, since it's being used to half-wave rectify the AC feeding it, the LED will only be ON half the time so it's OK to push twice its maximum continuous If through it. That being said, the formula for the ballast resistor becomes Rs = (Vs - Vf)/2I. Two caveats: The output voltage of a small transformer can often exceed its loaded rating by 30%, and the full peak value of the output voltage will be placed across the LED when it's reverse biased by the AC across it